# How to zoom while keeping the previous rotation transform as it is?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have an imageView, to which, I have added UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer.

in pinch gesture, I transform and scale the View and in rotation gesture I apply rotation transform to   it.

The problem is when I rotate the imageView and then start zooming. Zooming always begins from the normal state.

So What i want is when I rotate it to say 30 degree clockwise and then zoom it. it should zoom while remaining that 30 degree on the clockwise direction.

**Here is the code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

//setting up the image view

mTotalRotation = 0.0;
self.imageView.image = self.photo;
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *twoFingersRotate = 
[[[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingersRotate:)] autorelease];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingersRotate];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchZoom:)] autorelease];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
// Rotation gesture handler
- (void)twoFingersRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{


if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    mTotalRotation += recognizer.rotation;
    return;
}

self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(mTotalRotation + recognizer.rotation);         


}


   // Pinch Gesture

   -(void)pinchZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{


    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale) ;



}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to rotate and zoom the image view?

Comment: Check this tutorial: [UIGestureRecognizer Tutorial in iOS 5: Pinches, Pans, and More!](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) If You already know how to handle Gesture Recognizers, jump to *Simultaneous Gesture Recognizers*

Comment: @sch: Please check now. I have added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line:

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(mTotalRotation + recognizer.rotation);
```

with:

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, recognizer.rotation);
```

And the line:

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
```

with:

```
self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imageView.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
```

Edit

To limit the scale, you can do the following:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = self.imageView.transform;
float newScale = recognizer.scale * sqrt(transform.a*transform.a + transform.c*transform.c);
if (newScale > scaleLimit) {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
}
```

Comment: I did this straight after watching the ray wenderlich tutorial.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more
 Is there anyway I can check if I am not zooming it in to a certain level. I want to limit it to 1/2 the size, not lesser than that. Something like scrollViews minimumZoomScale.

Comment: : Thanks a lot !!! I dont know how much time it would have taken me to find and understand the math behind transforms.  

btw there is just one problem, we need to set the recognizer's scale back to 1 after applying the scale and rotation back to 0.  Otherwise its zooming and rotating very fast !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have your scale and rotate view as a subview of a view that you zoom?